# Phoenix generator phoenix.gen.json vs mix phx.gen.json

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am wondering what the difference with `phoenix.gen.json` and `phx.gen.json` is.

I am currently using Phoenix 1.3. Ubuntu 16.04LTS. and The following version of Erlang/Elixir

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.5.1
```

With `phoenix.gen.json`:

```
$>  mix phoenix.gen.json Session sessions session_id:string
mix phoenix.gen.json is deprecated. Use phx.gen.json instead.
* creating web/controllers/session_controller.ex
* creating web/views/session_view.ex
* creating test/controllers/session_controller_test.exs
* creating web/views/changeset_view.ex
mix phoenix.gen.model is deprecated. Use phx.gen.schema instead.
* creating web/models/session.ex
* creating test/models/session_test.exs
* creating priv/repo/migrations/20170823190558_create_session.exs

Add the resource to your api scope in web/router.ex:

    resources "/sessions", SessionController, except: [:new, :edit]

Remember to update your repository by running migrations:

    $ mix ecto.migrate
```

With `phx.gen.json`:

```
$> mix phx.gen.json API ContentAsset content_assets content_id:integer
* creating lib/my_app_web/controllers/content_asset_controller.ex
* creating lib/my_app_web/views/content_asset_view.ex
* creating test/my_app_web/controllers/content_asset_controller_test.exs
* creating lib/my_app_web/views/changeset_view.ex
* creating lib/my_appi_web/controllers/fallback_controller.ex
* creating lib/my_app/api/content_asset.ex
* creating priv/repo/migrations/20170823191342_create_content_assets.exs
* creating lib/my_app/api/api.ex
* injecting lib/my_app/api/api.ex
* creating test/my_app/api/api_test.exs
* injecting test/my_app/api/api_test.exs

Add the resource to your :api scope in lib/my_app_web/router.ex:

    resources "/content_assets", ContentAssetController, except: [:new, :edit]


Remember to update your repository by running migrations:

    $ mix ecto.migrate
```

As we can see that these two generators do not generate the same set of files.

More over, when we run the development server. I am seeing the following errors from the `phx.gen.json` files.

```
$> mix phx.server
Compiling 12 files (.ex)

== Compilation error in file lib/my_app_web/views/content_asset_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/my_app_web/views/content_asset_view.ex:2: module MyAppWeb is not loaded and could not be found
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    lib/my_app_web/views/content_asset_view.ex:2: MyAppWeb.ContentAssetView (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The significant difference with phoenix.gen.json and phx.gen.json is the **context module**. It is a concept of "Bounded Context" from Domain-Driven Design.

> The context is an Elixir module that serves as an API boundary for the
>   given resource. A context often holds many related resources.
>   Therefore, if the context already exists, it will be augmented with
>   functions for the given resource. Note a resource may also be split
>   over distinct contexts (such as Accounts.User and Payments.User).

(https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Json.html)

In your case, you generated an **API** context module in ***lib/my_app/api/api.ex***.

You may want to rename to **API** context module to something like **Content**.

```
== Compilation error in file lib/my_app_web/views/content_asset_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/my_app_web/views/content_asset_view.ex:2: module MyAppWeb is not loaded and could not be found
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    lib/my_app_web/views/content_asset_view.ex:2: MyAppWeb.ContentAssetView (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Based on your error message, most likely the module **MyAppWeb** is not defined.

For more learning resource about context:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMO28ar0lW8&feature=youtu.be&t=12m21s

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html

http://phoenixframework.org/blog/phoenix-1-3-0-released